# Python. From Input_1 = 3, Input_2 = 15, will output 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, correct my code

Tags: python

> If `Input_2` is a multiple of `Input_1`, output all multiples of
>   `Input_1` from small to large until `Input_2` is output. Otherwise,
>   the output the remainder of `Input_2` divided by `Input_1`.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input_1 = 3, Input_2 = 15, will output 3, 6, 9, 12, 15`
> ```
>
> Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input_1 = 5, Input_2 = 9, will output 4
> ```

The piece of code below doesn't work, please review

```
def print_int(num1, num2): 
    if num1 == num2: 
        print(num1) 
    else: 
        print(num1) 
        if(num1<num2): 
            print_int(num1 + 1, num2) 
        else: 
            print_int(num1 - 1, num2)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't take the downvotes personally. What we're trying to indicate is that "Piece of code below doesn't work, please review" is very broad and not specific enough for us to be able to assist. Can you pinpoint **which line** is not working as expected and **why** ?

Comment: your code will not work as expected, it will only print all the numbers from 3 to 15 for the first input. It would be something like this : 3, 4, 5, 6, ... 15 . I haven't tested it but it should work like I said.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work properly it will print all the number from smaller number to larger number because of the second `print()` statement in the `else` part of your logic.

This is what I did. Hope this helps.

```
def print_int2(a, b):
    if a > b : # I want a to be always smaller
        temp = b
        b = a
        a = temp
    if b % a == 0: # check multiple
        temp = a
        while a <= b : # print while incrementing everytime
            print a
            a += temp
    else : # otherwise the reminder.
        print b % a

print_int2(3, 15)
print('-'*10)
print_int2(5, 9)
```

Expected output :

```
3
6
9
12
15
----------
4
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you think the code you posted will perform the required tasks, what it actually does is quite different, so there isn't much point trying to review it. (Besides, Stack Overflow is *not* a site for code review. There *is* a Code Review Stack Exchange site, but code submitted there must work correctly).

Here's how I would write that function:

```
def print_int(num1, num2): 
    rem = num2 % num1
    if rem:
        print(rem)
    else:
        for i in range(num1, num2+1, num1):
            print(i)

# Test

print_int(5, 9)
print()
print_int(3, 15)
```

**output**

```
 4

3
6
9
12
15
```